# "Internship at" or "Internship in"?

Tags: grammar, prepositions

Which one is correct in what case?

[I have found](http://forum.wordreference.com/showthread.php?t=948648&langid=3) someone suggesting that you use "at" for organizations and "in" for fields or disciplines, e.g.,

> I've got an internship at NATO, and he's got an internship at Red Hat, but she's going for an internship in engineering.

These are clear, but there are corner cases less clear to me. For instance, would you say:

- *"I've got an internship **at** the department of psychiatry at a hospital in Boston"*; or
- *"I've got an internship **in** the department of psychiatry at a hospital in Boston"*?

...since here we are speaking of a place, however the emphasis lies on the discipline. Or are both fine?

Comment: A similar common expression is "an internship _with_ such-and-such".

Comment: Is there any any reason why 'internship' should differ from 'job, position, or appointment' in terms of the prepositions it takes?

Comment: @WS2 I don't see any reasons why it should differ. You may apply the answer here to all the other nouns you mentioned as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the rule referenced is quite clear in this regard, actually. The "department" is not the field of study itself, but rather "an organization" within the larger institution.

> *"I've got an internship at the department of psychiatry at a hospital in Boston"*